# Information(matter or energy)

Tags: knowledge, idea, information, philosophy-of-information

What is information? Is information matter or energy or neither but how can neither be possible. If we assume it to be either matter or energy then it must be following the laws of conservation. If yes then according to the law it must be correct to say that we cannot create nor destroy information then how can we create new ideas.if we consider for example a smartphone. The idea(information about a smartphone should have always existed) for us to come up with the idea about a smartphone? Is it possible that the information about everythings there is or there will be is already there in a scattered form and we are just gathering it and arranging at in a way.

Comment: Now apply the same argument to "being inside". Is "being inside" matter or energy? Either way, it must be conserved, so you can never drink a soda without filling another bottle to conserver insideness. The failure is in your premise that everything must be either matter or energy. There are lots more possibilities.

Comment: What is color? Is it matter or energy? It is neither, it is a property of matter, and so is information. Nor does it *have* to be conserved, some properties are and others are not. It is hard to see a philosophical question here, especially one answerable without venting opinions.

Comment: Information is pattern. Pattern of matter or energy or anything.

Comment: The distinction to be made here is between information, which is neither matter nor energy, and various *representations* of information, which do require matter and energy. It's a bit like the plot of a novel. The physical representation of the novel is printed on paper or lives in the memory of your Kindle device. Or it can be made into a movie. But the plot itself transcends the physical medium. It's a pure idea, separate from any particular representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brain and body are not reconstructed near the horizon. Say that a memory of my childhood (not that long ago...) is engraved into an nice pattern of connection strengths (widened synapses) between neurons in my brain and that a neural electric process runs with least resistance on them. I remember the childhood scene when I fall into the hole. Nobody knows the true nature of physical charges (be it electric or color), so the conscious experience cannot be explained. So the experience is linked to a material process in my brain and body. The material process doesn't explain it though. It merely states that someone has the conscious memory of childhood. The moment you fall in, there is only an entanglement realized between all the particle making you up and virtual particle states on the horizon. What is not included though are the interactions all these particles have with one another. The virtual particles, once realized, do not have the causal connections that exist in you falling in.

Take the childhood memory. The vacuum just above the horizon is entangled with literally all particles involved in the memory. Once realized these virtual particles won't interact to form a brain. They are not produced at once nor with the same spatial relationships as yours. They get real by the strong curvature and annihilate with their anti's giving through the information to photons that escape.

Note that all virtual particle in the vacuum near the horizon are entangled. In agreement with the maximum information that can be contained in the hole. Or better, the maximum information contained on the horizon, as the stuff inside the hole is no literal information (though in formation), but that which the information is about.

So information is existing in form. Consider a while canvas and a black one. The white canvas corresponds to very high (infinite) temperature of a collection of particles, which all move chaotically bumping. The entropy is maximal and so is the information needed to describe it. There is little in form though.
The black canvas corresponds to the same particles at zero kelvin. There is a strict order. Zero entropy, a minimum of information is needed to describe it. All is in strict immutable form.

The black and white canvases seem extremely different. But actually they are quite close to each other. The particles corresponding to the black painting contain minimum free Gibbs energy. Minimal entropy. Easy to describe globally.
The particles corresponding to the white canvas contain a maximum of free Gibbs energy and maximal entropy. Easy to describe globally.

The interesting case is the in-between case. Lines and patches of black forming patterns. Medium entropy, medium free Gibbs energy, and difficult to describe globally.
The black and white contain extremal entropy, a minimum and maximum value. But to both only one global picture is attached. To the entropy value of the in-between case, there is a huge variety of globally different pictures is attached. Math symbols and letters, numbers, and lots of drawings!